# Yii UrlManager not working

Tags: php, url, yii, url-routing

I am having Yii UrlManager issue.

I want to have following url: `localhost/mylist/this-is-demo-content`

It is working fine by:

```
'urlManager'=>array(
            'urlFormat'=>'path',
            'showScriptName' => false,
            'rules'=>array(
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
                '<controller:\w+>/<title:\w-]+>' => '<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<id1:\w+>'=>'<controller>/view',
                '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>'=>'<controller>/<action>',
            ),
```

But when I try `localhost/mylist/this`, it says

> no action found "this"

Here `mylist` is controller and I have one action

```
public function actionView($title)
{
    echo $title;
}
```

I have also tried this url pattern:

```
'<controller:\w+>/<title:[A-Z a-z 0-9 _ -]+>' => '<controller>/view',
```

but could not work

Comment: I would be more strict with this, like `'mylist/<title:[A-Z a-z 0-9 _ -]+>' => 'mylist/view',`. Also on `'<controller:\w+>/<title:\w-]+>' => '<controller>/view'` you miss `[`.

Comment: That is right but it also affects another controller and its action like, I am unable to open mylist/logout as it searches logout in the view action

Comment: Can you add a list of all the routes you'd like to support? If you want to use pattern-matching, you should to directly specify routes that need to work outside of those patterns.

Comment: You're also missing an opening `[` in the second rule, unless you're saying you want to actually match the `]` character

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Continue from these simplified rules:

```
    'rules'=>array(
        // Place custom rules here
        'mylist/<title>' => 'mylist/view',

        // Nothing should go below these default rules
        '<controller:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/view',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
        '<controller:\w+>/<action:\w+>/<id:\d+>' => '<controller>/<action>',
    ),
```